# android - saving int with sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

In my new app a counter increases when the button is clicked. I want to save the highscore with sharedPreferences, so the score is saved and shown the next time the app is started. The problem is that I don't really get it working, even with other answered questions.

```
package com.example.test;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public int score = 0;
    public int highscore = 0;
    TextView tvscore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tvhighscore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
        tvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        Button count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        tvhighscore.setText(String.valueOf(highscore));

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("score", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("score", 0);
        editor.commit();



    }

    public void onClick (View view) {
        score++;
        tvscore.setText(String.valueOf(score));

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int highscore = prefs.getInt("score", 0); 
    }


}
```

Comment: need to save score in `SharedPreferences` on click of Button

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K is right. Plus make sure you are using the same name for the shared preferences file.

Comment: Am I not using the same name `"score"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use the same key for the shared preferences when writing and querying. Then also in onclick you need to store the score in the prefs and not query it again. Here's the updated code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        public int score = 0;
        public int highscore;
        TextView tvscore, tvhighscore;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tvhighscore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
            tvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            Button count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


            SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            highscore = prefs.getInt("high_score", 0);
            tvhighscore.setText(String.valueOf(highscore));
        }

        public void onClick (View view) {
            score++;
            tvscore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            if (score > highscore) {
                highscore = score;
                SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                prefs.edit().putInt("high_score", highscore).apply();
                tvhighscore.setText(String.valueOf(highscore));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code

**First error is that you are using different names for SP**

`SharedPreferences` are accessed via an `unique key`. in your code you have two of them: `myPrefsKey` and `myPrefsKey`. Be sure of using always the same or the value will not be found.

**The second is that you are using two times the same int name**

Both in code and in `onclick` method you are casting an `int` with the same name `highscore`. This is not allowed

**The third is in logics:**

What you are doing is:

- Saving value on `activity` start.
- Reading value on `button` click

While you should do the following:

- Read the value in `onCreate` method using the getInt code you are using inside the `button` click and setting the `textview's` text with it.
- Save the value on `button` click after incrementing it.

This way you will have the code working.

Below an example:

```
package com.example.test;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public int score = 0;
    public int highscore = 0;
    TextView tvscore;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tvhighscore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
        tvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        Button count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //here you retrieve the value of the highscore
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int highscore = prefs.getInt("score", 0); 
        tvhighscore.setText(String.valueOf(highscore));



    }

    public void onClick (View view) {
        score++;
        //here you save the value of the score in your pref
        tvscore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("score", score);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Dunno if this is exactly what you were looking for, but this should help you understanding the logics :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a class to manage your sp.
   I leave you an example below.

```
  public class SharedPrefsManager {
    private static final String USER_CODE = "userCode";
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

    private static void setPreferences(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            context = Application.getContext();
        }
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("APP_NAME", 0);
    }

    public static int getCodigoUsuario(Context context) {
        setPreferences(context);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(USER_CODE, 0);
    }

    public static void setCodigoUsuario(int userCode, Context context) { 
        setPreferences(context);
        prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt(USER_CODE, userCode);
        prefEditor.commit();
    } 
   }
```

> SAVE: SharedPrefsManager.setCodigoUsuario(13, context);
>
> GET SharedPrefsManager.getCodigoUsuario(context);

Comment: SharedPrefsManager.setCodigoUsuario(user, context);